# Add range dynamically to list

Tags: c#, list, types, type-conversion

I have a `List<byte>` that stores the value of a variable `byte` by `byte`. I am trying to build up this variable by respect to its original data type.

Example of the result:

```
List<byte> varBytes = new List<byte>();

varBytes.Add(0x12);
varBytes.Add(0x34);
varBytes.Add(0x56);
varBytes.Add(0x78);

//After the conversion of UInt32:
varReady = 0x78563412;
```

Here is a snippet of my class that returns the value of the variable.

```
public static object GetTypedString(List<byte> varBytes, string varType)
{
    object varReady;

    switch (varType)
    {
        case "uint16":

            UInt16 varReady = BitConverter.ToUInt16(varBytes.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
            break;

        case "uint32":

            UInt32 varReady = BitConverter.ToUInt32(varBytes.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
            break;

        //repeat case for each data type
    }

    return varReady ;
}
```

The problem comes up if my variable is only 2 bytes long and if I want to show that variable as `UInt32`. The `BitConverter.ToUInt32` will throw this exception:

`Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection.`

Because the `varBytes` list only has 2 bytes but `BitConverter.ToUInt32` is trying to read 4 bytes. My solution was to add dummy bytes to the end of the list in this case:

```
.
.
.
case "uint32":

    int difference = sizeof(UInt32) - varSize; //we know the variable size already
    if(difference > 0)
    {
        varToDisp.value.AddRange(new byte[difference]);
    }

    UInt32 varReady = BitConverter.ToUInt32(varBytes.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
    break;
.
.
.
```

This works but didn't seem a good way to me since it will edit the original `List` and consumes some time. Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Your `GetTypedString` method will not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I had simplified the code to paste here. I added `return` value and it should be okay now.

Comment: it seems to be working, it returns 2018915346 https://dotnetfiddle.net/4gCLmm

Comment: yes, it works very well but I was curious about if it is possible to do it easier and faster to convert.

Comment: Does the byte array originate from an `UInt32`? If so, why didn't you save the original two zero bytes? If not, why don't you solve this at the output side by casting?

Comment: Original datatype does not matter. We just build the variable with the data type requested by the user. A 32-bit number can be represented in `float` or `UInt32`. So the user can pick a datatype which has a size bigger than the original size of the variable.

Comment: for UInt32 the length of the array must be at least 4

Comment: @SergiuMuresan I know, this is why I'm adding dummy bytes to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the *array* (not list) with required `Length` with a help of *Linq* `Concat`; I suggest routine redesign as well.

**Code:**

```
// Let's implement a generic method: we want, say, uint not object from given list
public static T GetTypedString<T>(List<byte> varBytes) where T: struct {
  if (null == varBytes)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(varBytes));

  // sizeof alternative 
  // char is Ascii by default when marshalling; that's why Marshal.SizeOf returns 1 
  int size = typeof(T) == typeof(char)
    ? sizeof(char)
    : System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

  // if data is too short we should pad it; either from left or from right:
  // {0, ..., 0} + data or data + {0, ..., 0}
  // to choose the way, let's have a look at endiness 
  byte[] data = (size >= varBytes.Count)
    ? BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
       ? varBytes.Concat(new byte[size - varBytes.Count]).ToArray()
       : new byte[size - varBytes.Count].Concat(varBytes).ToArray()
    : varBytes.ToArray();

  // A bit of reflection: let's find out suitable Converter method
  var mi = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod($"To{typeof(T).Name}");

  if (null == mi)
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {typeof(T).Name} can't be converted");
  else
    return (T)(mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { data, 0 })); // or data.Length - size
}
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
List<byte> varBytes = new List<byte>();

varBytes.Add(0x12);
varBytes.Add(0x34);
varBytes.Add(0x56);
varBytes.Add(0x78);

int result1 = GetTypedString<int>(varBytes);
long result2 = GetTypedString<long>(varBytes);

Console.WriteLine(result1.ToString("x")); 
Console.WriteLine(result2.ToString("x")); 

// How fast it is (Linq and Reflection?)
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

int n = 10000000;

sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  // The worst case: 
  //  1. We should expand the array
  //  2. The output is the longest one  
  long result = GetTypedString<long>(varBytes); 

  //Trick: Do not let the compiler optimize the loop
  if (result < 0)
    break;
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Microseconds per operation: {(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds/n*1000000)}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
78563412
78563412
Microseconds per operation: 0.84716933
```

**Edit:** If you insist on *type name* (`string varType`) instead of generic parameter `<T>` first of all let's extract a model (type name - type correspondense):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Type> s_Types = 
  new Dictionary<string, Type>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "uint16", typeof(UInt16)},
    { "ushort", typeof(UInt16)}, // <- you can add synonyms if you want
    { "int", typeof(Int32)},
    { "int32", typeof(Int32)},
    { "long", typeof(Int64)},
    { "int64", typeof(Int64)}, 
    //TODO: add all the other names and correspondent types
};
```

Then you can implement it as

```
public static object GetTypedString(List<byte> varBytes, string varType) {
  if (null == varBytes)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(varBytes));
  else if (null == varType)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(varType));

  Type type = null;

  if (!s_Types.TryGetValue(varType, out type))
    throw new ArgumentException(
      $"Type name {varType} is not a valid type name.", 
        nameof(varBytes));

  // sizeof alternative 
  // char is Ascii by default when marshalling; that's why Marshal.SizeOf returns 1 
  int size = typeof(T) == typeof(char)
    ? sizeof(char)
    : System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

  byte[] data = (size >= varBytes.Count)
    ? BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
       ? varBytes.Concat(new byte[size - varBytes.Count]).ToArray()
       : new byte[size - varBytes.Count].Concat(varBytes).ToArray()
    : varBytes.ToArray();

  var mi = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod($"To{type.Name}");

  if (null == mi)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
      $"Type {type.Name} (name: {varType}) can't be converted");
  else
    return mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { data, 0 }); // data.Length - size
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string result1 = (GetTypedString(varBytes, "Int64") as IFormattable).ToString("x8", null);
```

Comment: looks nice, but I won't recommend Reflection mostly for performance reasons.

Comment: This is a bit more than I could do but I'm trying to understand it now. If I can get this work, it will be a shorter solution for me. But I don't know much about the performance issues. I'm running a data logger and speed is very important for me. Do you think this solution will be slower than the `switch-case` method?

Comment: @abdullah cinar: Reflection which I've used is not very fast (we have to find out method by its name), that's why `switch/case`, `Dcitionary<Type, Func>` or even `if else if` will be faster

Comment: @abdullah cinar: Since you run a *looger* you want a `string` as an outcome (i.e. what to write into log). Could you, please, state the initial problem. Do you really want to convert `list` into any structure (`int`, `double`, `ulong` etc.)? But may be just expand (if necessary) the list and write it down? string `result = string.Concat(varBytes.Select(item => item.ToString("x2")));`

Comment: I need a `string` outcome for the `watch window` but I also need the structure `(int, double etc)` for my `scope window` where I will plot the variables in a chart. I was just converting them to string after getting the actual value.

Comment: @abdullah cinar: it took about `400 nanoseconds` per call (in case of `Int32`)  and `800 nanoseconds` in case of (`Int64`) at my workstation (less than `1 microsecond` in any case).

Comment: It's actually fast enough for me. I'm just trying to understand the solution since I have never used a generic method before. I will accept the solution after I test it. Thanks!

Comment: It worked very well. Is there any way to pass my `string varType` to this method? I don't want to add a new case for every datatype just for calling this method. Can we just use a use a `string` as a datatype input? This way I can just call this method once by using my `string varType` as the datatype selection.

Comment: @abdullah cinar: you can obtain `Type` from its `string` name with a help of Dictionary<string, Type>` and then use the rest of the routine (see my edit, please)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I found out that `Marshal.SizeOf(type)` is equal to `1` for the type `Char` but it is actually 2 bytes long when you try to use`BitConverter.ToChar`. So I had to add an exception for it.

Comment: @abdullah cinar: you are quite right, `char` is an exceptional case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Type_
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `.ToArray` you could preallocate your array to the correct size and use `.CopyTo`.

Example:

```
var byteArray = new byte[sizeof(UInt32)];
varBytes.CopyTo(byteArray);

UInt32 varReady = BitConverter.ToUInt32(byteArray, 0);
```

Comment: you need to validate the length of the varBytes list. If there are more than 4 bytes in this list then you'll get the error: "Destination array was not long enough. " because you are trying to copy a, lets say, 8 bytes array over a 4 bytes array.

Comment: Yes, I just got that error. So now the initial problem just changed the way. I don't want to add a condition for every data type because I will have at least 10 different data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the length of the array and convert it to smaller types then cast the required one

```
case "uint32":
{
    if (varBytes.Count == 1)
    {
        varReady = (UInt32)varBytes[0];
    }
    else if (varBytes.Count >= 2 && varBytes.Count < 4)
    {
        varReady = (UInt32)BitConverter.ToUInt16(varBytes.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
    }
    else
    {
        varReady = BitConverter.ToUInt32(varBytes.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the user wants to convert them to `UInt64`, I will need to add another condition too.